# AJAX - Render Async Request to DOM

Tags: json, ajax, for-loop

I’m using a for loop iterate a JSON object and return results. The results are displayed on the webpage when a button is clicked.

Using the slice method I’m able to limit the results, however, subsequent button clicks reload the same five entries instead of the next five in the list.

```
listOfFlavors = () => {
    axios.get(`http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/${strainAPI}/searchdata/flavors`)
        .then(function (response) {
            let flavors = response.data.slice(0, 5)
            for (let i = 0, len = flavors.length; i < len; i++) {
                let li = document.createElement('li')

                li.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(flavors[i])
                document.querySelector('.flavors-list').appendChild(li)


            }
            // handle success
            console.log(response.data.slice(0, 5));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
}

if (getFlavors) {
    getFlavors.addEventListener('click', listOfFlavors)
}
```

[image]
How can one create an async request that will return a specified number of results on each click?

For example,

First click – display 1-5

Second click – display 6-10

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either change the server API so you pass a parameter telling it where you're up to and it only returns 5 results, or hold a variable which tells you the current values to slice on.

Either way you need to store a value in a higher scope than your ajax call and then update that value when the ajax completes.

Here's an example of the second approach:

```
var sliceVals = [0, 5];

listOfFlavors = () => {
    axios.get(`http://strainapi.evanbusse.com/${strainAPI}/searchdata/flavors`)
        .then(function (response) {
//notice the use of variables in slice instead of fixed values
            let flavors = response.data.slice(sliceVals[0], sliceVals[1]);
            //now increment the values for next time
            sliceVals[0] += 5;
            sliceVals[1] += 5;

            for (let i = 0, len = flavors.length; i < len; i++) {
                let li = document.createElement('li')

                li.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(flavors[i])
                document.querySelector('.flavors-list').appendChild(li)


            }
            // handle success
            console.log(response.data.slice(0, 5));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
}

if (getFlavors) {
    getFlavors.addEventListener('click', listOfFlavors)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your flavors array to hold next slice of elements.You can pass a from parameter to your method and set it as a starting point to slice from to the next number of elements you want.